# Self Updating Excel Chart

Tags: charts

Looking for some help on excel chart without using VBA codes (if possible).

Team :1         $0.27,
Team :2         $0.90,
Team :3         $4.63,
Team :4         $5.32,
Team :5         $0.77,
Total           $11.88,

Above table provide total expenditure forecast for each teams for a future event. The data which will update on daily basis. I would like to plot a Line Graph to show progress/update for each day without expanding the table any further. Spending forecast for each team will change everyday & old data will be replaced with new.

My X-Axis will be date & Y-Axis will be spending.

Ques: Is excel 2016 capable of generating a Line Graph with data getting replaced (overwritten) everyday ? If yes, can some please help me here !!

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Had you made a graph and test it (change the data and see if the previously generated graph changes too) ?

Comment: I tried, when old data is replaced with new the dots on line graph aligns to date with creating a line.. only dots move around unfortunately..\

Comment: *without creating a line

Comment: "..to plot a Line Graph to show progress/update for each day without expanding the table any further" & "old data will be replaced with new." > Then, my technical question is..  can a graph a data that is no more there ? Right?  |  Without re-arranging the data structure.. it is impossible.

Comment: what i meant is.. think of a way to record the daily/new/updated data side by side.. then redraw the graph... I hope you can share the updated data structure/table.. then we can assist from there..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table that grows with every new date, you can employ the techniques of dynamic charting to plot only the last 6 rows (or some such).

If the number of rows and columns does not change, but the data is overwritten with new data, just create a chart off that source data and replace the data as it changes.

Edit: You say you don't want to expand the table. That means that the number of rows and columns of the table remains the same. Therefore you need to replace the data in the table to create a different chart.

If, however, you want the **chart** to grow over time, showing more and more data points, then the source table will also need to grow, because Excel cannot chart data that is not there.

Comment: If the number of rows and columns does not change, but the data is overwritten with new data, just create a chart off that source data and replace the data as it changes.

Comment: But if I replace source data, How can i plot a Line Graph ? sorry am I missing a point :(

Comment: I added to my answer. I think you need to edit your question and show what you want to achieve. Mock it up with the drawing tools.  You definitely cannot draw a line over time if you have only one value for one team.

Comment: Two (or more) points make a line. If you don't want to add data to the table, then each series only has one point, so no line. As stated in your similar question on MrExcel.com, you need to add the new data, not replace the old data with it.